# Seat reservation in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am doing a school project in C#, its basically a cinema administration application which includes adding movies, adding events(based on added movies) and adding reservations. I am using SQLite for an embedded database.

My problem is : I am trying to add some kind of graphic representation of the theatre, with all the seats represented by buttons, and i want these buttons to be either red if the seat was already reserved or green if available.

Here is a picture of what i want : [image: What i want]

What i did so far : I created the layout, i added 34 buttons and i have the next code :

```
        //If the textbox is empty, then this place will be the first
        if (textBox5.Text == "")
        {
            textBox5.Text = "A5";
        }
        //If the textbox is not empty, then it will add a comma and a space between seats
        else
        {
            textBox5.Text = textBox5.Text + ", " + "A5";
        }
```

The seats are saved in a textbox then sent into the database, in a column named "seats" from "reserves" table. My issue is that i dont know how to make these buttons check if the place is or is not available, should i change the whole procedure?

Comment: Your question feels like you stopped half way.  First of all we have no idea what procedure you are suggesting be changed -- but more importantly what don't you know how to do??  To have the buttons "check" you will need code that access the database to get a list of reserved seats and then loop over that dataset and change the color of these buttons.  This is simple and obvious -- so what exactly is your question?

Comment: I thought it was clear he has done 2% of the work and is asking someone else to do the other 98%.

Comment: For me looping over dataset isnt too simple, and you got it right, thats my problem

Comment: @stark actually the seat checking part isnt even required, i did 100% of the required homework, this is just extra for myself

Comment: @Hogan If you can help me a little more with some examples of what you just said i would be grateful

Comment: No.  The outline I gave should be enough -- if you need more help consult the FAQ about how to ask a question here, I'm not doing free consulting work.  If you give a serious attempt at what I describe and have a problem or question post it here and I or someone else will help you with that problem but we are not going to write the program for you.